# How can I find the claims of US 918,884, which are not listed on Google Patents?

Tags: claims, us918884

In reference to patent [US 918,884](https://www.google.com/patents/US918884), where can I go to find the claims of this patent?

Google Patents appears to have a recursive link for where to find them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any part of the patent document using one of the following methods:

- View PDF: this button opens the scan image file on they fly and user can scroll to relevant section for information.
- Download PDF: this button downloads the PDF copy on device.
- Using the external Links for USPTO and Espacenet.
- External Link USPTO: provides text of patent application and user can view images in TIFF format.
- External Link Espacenet: provides a complete bibliography and scanned copy of the document.

For your query please follow any of the above methods. The steps are shown below:

[image: illustrated step-by-step process to find claims]

Comment: This answer is correct, but it should also be noted that since this is an old patent from 1909, the claims are not formatted as they are in modern documents (patents have undergone several major revisions, the most profound ones in the 1940's and 1950's). The patent has been scanned with OCR, and was basically interpreted by Google as if it were a contemporary patent, which is why the text version of the claims are missing.